# How can include a less than where statement from the case statement in this query?

Tags: postgresql

I only want to show results for 90 days or less in this query I've written :

```
SELECT
 (amount / 100) as "Reel_$",
   CASE
   WHEN savingstrategyfrequency = 'day' THEN CEIL(((total - (successfulamount + pendingamount)) * 1.00) / savingstrategyamount)
    WHEN savingstrategyfrequency = 'week' THEN CEIL(((total - (successfulamount + pendingamount)) * 1.00) / ((savingstrategyamount * 1.00) / 7))
 END AS days_to_complete
FROM prodjoinreel.goals
WHERE
 status IN ('active')
```

but when I include the following where statement: 
`where status IN ('active') and days_to_complete < 90`
 I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either repeat the expression, or use a subquery (or cte):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        (amount / 100) as "Reel_$",
        CASE
            WHEN savingstrategyfrequency = 'day' 
                THEN CEIL(((total - (successfulamount + pendingamount)) * 1.00) / savingstrategyamount)
            WHEN savingstrategyfrequency = 'week' 
                THEN CEIL(((total - (successfulamount + pendingamount)) * 1.00) / ((savingstrategyamount * 1.00) / 7))
        END AS days_to_complete
    FROM prodjoinreel.goals
    WHERE status IN ('active')
) t
WHERE days_to_complete < 90
```